# Bipartite connected graph proof

Tags: graph, graph-theory, proof, bipartite

A friend presented me with a conjecture that seems to be true but neither of us can come up with a proof. Here's the problem:

> Given a connected, bipartite graph with disjoint non-empty vertex sets U and V, such that |U|<|V|, all vertices are in either U or V, and there are no edges connecting two vertices within the same set, then there exists at least one edge which connects vertices a∈U and b∈V such that degree(a)>degree(b)

It's trivial to prove that there is at least one vertex in U with degree higher than one in V, but to prove that a pair exists *with an edge connecting them* is stumping us.

Comment: It's trivially false as stated (since you can pick U empty). Are your U and V supposed to cover the graph, and have no internal edges?

Comment: Yes, sorry, U and V are the sets that make the graph bipartite. They contain all vertices and have no internal edges. I edited to make that clearer.

Answer (score 2):

For any edge e=(a,b) with a∈U and b∈V, let w(e)=1/deg(b)-1/deg(a). For any vertex x, the sum of 1/deg(x) over all edges incident with x equals 1, because there are deg(x) such edges. Hence, the sum of w(e) over all edges e equals |V|-|U|. Since |V|-|U|>0, w(e)>0 for som edge e=(a,b), which means that deg(a)>deg(b).

Answer (score 0):

Prove it by contradiction, i.e. suppose that *deg(a) ≤ deg(b) ∀(a,b)∈E*, where *E* is the edgeset of the graph (with the convention that the first element is in *U* and the second in *V*).

For F⊆E, designate by *V(F)* the subset of *V* which is reachable through edgeset *F*, that is:

*V(F) = { b | (a,b)∈F }*

Now build an edgeset *F* as follows:

```
F = empty set
For a ∈ U:
    add any edge (a,b)∈E to F
Keep adding arbitrary edges (a,b)∈E to F until |V(F)| = |U|
```

The set *V(F)* obtained is connected to all nodes in *U*, hence by our assumption we must have

*∑<sub>a∈U</sub> deg(a) ≤ ∑<sub>b∈V(F)</sub> deg(b)*

However, since *|U|=|V(F)|* and *|U|<|V|*  we know that there must be at least one "unreached" node *v∈V\V(F)*, and since the graph is connected, *deg(v)>0*, so we obtain

*∑<sub>a∈U</sub> deg(a) < ∑<sub>b∈V</sub> deg(b)*

which is impossible; this should be an equality for a bipartite graph.